# Different domains with the same Website Name

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

Is it possible to set different domains on one website name in Magento 1.9?

I want to have it like this:
[image]

Is it even possible to set this in store level?

EDIT: 
I also did the costumisation in index.php file

```
if(stripos($http_host, 'mywebsite.de') !== false){
    $mageRunCode = "mywebsite";
    $mageRunType = "website";
}elseif(stripos($http_host, 'mywebsite.com') !== false){
    $mageRunCode = "mywebsite";
    $mageRunType = "website";
}
```

and set the Base URL on different Current Configuration Scopes.

Answer (score 4):

> Yes, you just need to create a default **store** and **view** to each one.

---

You can Manage your stores like that on **System > Manage Stores**.

[image: Manage Store]

You will need to change the scope to define the **base URL** like that image below.

[image: Base URL on Store View]

Some devs change the  **index.php** like that below.

> But the better way to handle switching the run code and run type is to use your **Apache** or **Nginx** configuration on the Virtual Host instead of modifying a "core" file (index.php).

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case "www.store2.com":
    case "store2.com":
        $mageRunCode="base2";
        $mageRunType="website";
        break;
    default:
        $mageRunCode="base";
        $mageRunType="website";
        break;
}
```

Comment: An how do i connect it to the different domains?

Comment: Point all the domains to the same server, and in the configuration set the proper (secure) base url for the specific stores. Magento will do the rest.

Comment: Rafael's comment is 99% correct.  The better way to handle switching the run code and run type is to use your Apache or Nginx configuration on the Virtual Host instead of modifying a "core" file (index.php).

Answer (score 1):

In **System** -> **Manage Stores** you can create Website, stores and stores views.

Create Website: *mywebsite*, Create Store: *mywebsite.de* and *mywebsite.com*, Create Store View: English, French and German for each stores.

In **System** -> **Configuration** choose Current Configuration Scope and set the settings *Base Url* of each domain for *Secure* or *Unsecure* in the Web tab